# Candy Conundrum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Could somebody please help me in second part of this question?

I have two bowls of candy. One is supposed to be filled with candy-covered chocolates, the other filled with fruit-flavored candies with candy shells. Unfortunately, someone has nefariously mixed up the contents of the two bowls, mixing a portion of one bowl into the second, and vice versa. Even worse, the candies are indistinguishable visually, and can only be sorted out by taste.

I know that one of the bowls (A) has candies in the following proportions: A ~ {2/3 chocolate, 1/3 fruity}, while the other bowl (B) has candies in the following proportion: B ~ {1/4 chocolate, 3/4 fruity}. Assume for the questions below that both bowls are large enough that small samples will not have a practical effect on the distribution of candies.

1. I select a bowl at random and choose a random candy. It's a chocolate candy! What is the probability that I've picked up bowl A (the one weighted towards chocolates)? 8/11 . I answered that.
2. Continuing with the same bowl as before, I select two more candies. They are both fruity candies. What is the probability that I've picked up bowl A (the one weighted towards chocolates) now? (To clarify, there are three candies drawn in all: one chocolate and two fruity.)

Thanks in advance. Please help me in the second one,

Comment: you can proceed just as in the first part. There you assumed the unconditional probabilities to be 1/2 for each bowl. Now you can keep going, but for the second candy drawn, take 8/11 and 3/11 to be the prior (unconditional) probabilities, and find ones that are conditional on drawing a fruity. Then one more time (with adjusted priors) for the second fruity. (Or, you can consider the second and third draws as a single event - calculate its probabilities accordingly.)